# iOS Swift: UITapGestureRecognizer and Storyboard

Tags: ios, design-patterns, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I am a novice at iOS programming, obviously a novice at Swift (as it is new), and a dabbler at best in programming overall over the past ~35 years. I have, however, worked for the past 20 years as a manager of multidisciplinary teams that include programmers and as a result I understand a lot of fundamental concepts of software design. I provide this information for context.

I am working on a database app for a class and adding a lot of functionality of my own choosing to enhance my own learning experience. I yesterday wanted to allow users to tap a UIImageView to choose a new picture for the database entry. I added a Tap Gesture Recognizer to the UIImageView and hooked up the IBAction to the appropriate view controller then added a println() to the IBAction to test whether it was being recognized. Taps on the UIImageView didn't produce the println() and I was frustrated, so I looked around on the tubes for some hints and found some sample code to programmatically recognize the tap:

```
 let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("didTap:"))
 recognizer.delegate = self
 view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
```

This worked a treat, as they say. I was frustrated, however, as I saw a lot of reference to the idea that the code was unnecessary if I was using the storyboard. After a bit of experimentation with a test project, I eventually found that the UIImageView had to have "User Interaction Enabled" in the Attributes Inspector (not the default setting) to recognize user interaction, which in hindsight makes sense.

My question (at last!) is whether the difference between the two approaches is stylistic or whether there is a reason to choose to do it programmatically over the implementation via storyboard. For performance or delegation or otherwise. I can, for example, see that I could embed the recognition code in an if statement. Are there other reasons?

Is this question too theoretical for this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, I always use storyboards unless and until I encounter something that has to be done in code. It's just conceptually easier for me to understand the overall shape of the app if I can see it in large, interconnected chunks. There shouldn't be any noticeable performance differences.

Regarding your particular example, whenever I have an image that has to be tappable, I just put the image in a `UIButton`, and hook the button up to an `IBAction` in the controller. This obviates the need for adding a custom gesture recognizer and remembering to make the image tappable.

Comment: Lack of activity on the topic leads me to believe the answer is "personal style". I'll mark it answered. Thanks!